# Consider a hash which can be accessed and updated anywhere in a rails application without a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, hash

An application which performs CRUD operations without the database accessing data via csv file .I wanna store the data from csv file into the hash . I have considered this method but end up errors .

```
  employee.rb    
    class Employee
    include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON
   include ActiveModel::Validations
 include ActiveModel::Model
 include ActiveModel::Dirty

  attr_accessor  :id, :name , :email , :number , :salary 

  define_attribute_methods  :id, :name , :email , :number , :salary
   validates :name, presence: true,  length: { maximum: 100 }

 def attributes
  {'id' => nil , 'name' => nil , 'email' => nil , 'number' => nil ,     'salary' => nil }
   end

   def self.find(id)
   p ' fof fof fof fof o'
   p @employees
   raw = Parse.get("employee", id.to_s)

   employee = Employee.new
   employee.id = raw["id"]
   employee.name = raw["name"]
   employee.email = raw["email"] 
   employee.number = raw["number"] 
   employee.salary = raw["salary"] 

 #  etc for the others

 p  employee # Return the newly-created instance
      end

   def capitalized_name
    name.capitalize
end

  def self.all
     ObjectSpace.each_object(self).to_a
   end
  end
```

employee_controller.rb

```
   class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

   require 'csv'



def index

CSV.foreach('data.csv') do |row|
    #Employee.create!(row.to_hash)
    a = []
    a = row.inspect 
    p a 
    a = a.gsub(/(\[\"|\"\])/, '').split('", "')
    p a 
     e = Employee.new 
     e.id = a[0]
     e.name = a[1]
     e.email = a[2]
     e.number = a[3]
     e.salary = a[4]
    #m  = e.serializable_hash
   # m = m.keys.zip(a).to_h
    employee_values = e.instance_values 
    all = Data.instance
    all.add("e.i = employee_values" )
end
@employees = ::Employee.all
p @employees
p "blah blah blah"
p all.keys 
end

 def new
   @employee = Employee.new
 end

 def edit
     @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
 end 

 def create
     @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @employee.save
    format.html { redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Employee was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @employee }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
 end

 def destroy
   @employee.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to employees_url, notice: 'Employee was successfully destroyed.' }
     format.json { head :no_content }
    end
   end

  private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
   def set_employee
     @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
   end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def employee_params
  params.require(:employee).permit(:id ,:name, :hiredate, :salary)
end
```

end

Then created a subclass for Hash to be accessed anywhere and saved it in initializers as creatting a global variable is bad practice 
         require 'singleton'

```
class Data < Hash
  include Singleton

  def initialize
   super([])
 end

 def add src
   src.to_s.split(";").each do |item|
    splitted = item.split("=")
    self[splitted[0]] = splitted[1]
  end
end
```

end

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally this is considered a bad idea for a variety of reasons. Mainly because you will have more than one Rails worker, and if you start putting something in the the hash on one worker, it will not be accessible in another worker - which means your users will see inconsistent data. Can you explain to us what you're doing this for? Perhaps there's a better way of achieving the result you want, but we can't tell you unless you explain the * result * you want rather than the method you've chosen to implement it.

Comment: well i have populated the data from the csv file but would like to do the CRUD operations . I populated the data by saving the instances of the data . To delete or edit , i thought i would move it to global hash maybe and hence show the new data .

Comment: Yes, but why do this in a local hash, instead of the database, which is where we do it normally?